# AVR plugins not able to install in Eclipse. It says missing requirements

Tags: eclipse

These are the things i followed in eclipse to download plug-ins.

1. First i went to the help option in eclipse and then install new software and it opened a window. In that i typed the site for avr plug-ins (http://avr-eclipse.sourceforge.net/updatesite/)
2. Then in the box below it showed just one option containing AVR Eclipse plug-in. then after selecting the option (i.e the avr eclipse plug-in).
3. Then after clicking next it was searching for requirements and dependencies and then the install details said that the install could not be completed

Details

```
(Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

  Software being installed: AVR Eclipse Plugin 2.4.1 (de.innot.avreclipse.feature.group 2.4.1)

  Missing requirement: de.innot.avreclipse.ui 2.4.1 requires 'bundle org.eclipse.cdt.core 4.0.1' but it could not be found

  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: AVR Eclipse Plugin 2.4.1 (de.innot.avreclipse.feature.group 2.4.1)

    To: de.innot.avreclipse.ui [2.4.1])
```

As shown in the internet on youtube I followed the above steps for installing avr plug-ins https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6aXn2en86aQ

In the 2nd step it was showing options

```
CDT optional features
1.AVR eclipse plugin 
2.AVR eclipse plugin sources
```

Please help me out friends.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the c/c++ (CDT) plugins for eclipse first, and make sure you have all the toolchains installed.

Toolchains:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-avr binutils-avr gdb-avr avr-libc avrdude
```

CDT:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt
```